# Message box closes form regardless of result

Tags: c#

i am new to message box buttons and it seems to close the form regardless.

```
private void btnFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Desjea Sair?", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You're setting the [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the form (this looks like `WinForms`), which always closes it.

Create a local variable inside your button click event:

```
private void btnFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Desjea Sair?", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

More on [Form.DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN:

> If the form is displayed as a dialog box, setting this property with a value from the DialogResult enumeration sets the value of the dialog box result for the form, **hides the modal dialog box**, and returns control to the calling form.

So if you're displaying the form using `ShowDialog()` as most of us do, then setting the form's DialogResult property causes it to close.